# RecyclerView выдает неверные данные

Tags: android, recyclerview

Не понимаю почему RecyclerView после выдачи нескольких элементов начинает подсовывать их заново, а тот, на котором начинаются ошибки, при свайпах вверх вниз может менять свои значения три раза. RecyclerView реализовано в фрагменте (если это важно). Несколько часов потратил на выяснение причин. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть дело?

```
    @Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_car_list, container, false);
    mRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.car_recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    updateUI();
    return view;
}

private class CarHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Car mCar;

    public CarHolder(@NonNull final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        mProducerTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.producerCardTextView);
        mModelTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.modelCardTextView);
        mPriceTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.priceCardTextView);
    }

    public void bind(Car car) {
        mCar = car;
        mProducerTextView.setText(getString(R.string.producer_params, mCar.getProducer()));
        mModelTextView.setText(getString(R.string.model_params, mCar.getModel()));
        mPriceTextView.setText(getString(R.string.price_params, mCar.getPrice()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mListCallBack.onCarSelected(mCar);
    }
}

private class CarAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CarHolder> {

    private List<Car> mCars;

    public CarAdapter(List<Car> cars) {
        mCars = cars;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CarHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_car, viewGroup, false);
        return new CarHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CarHolder carHolder, int i) {
        Car car = mCars.get(i);
        carHolder.bind(car);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mCars.size();
    }

    public void setCars(List<Car> cars) {
        this.mCars = cars;
    }
}

public void updateUI(){
    List<Car> cars = CarLab.getCarLab(getActivity()).getCars();
    if (mAdapter == null) {
        mAdapter = new CarAdapter(cars);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    } else {
        mAdapter.setCars(cars);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

[Видео происходящего](https://youtu.be/cEsJzGT-4KU)

Comment: в адаптере вроде нет никаких явных проблем, если это весь код. видимо причина в другом месте.

Comment: не представляю в каком месте может быть, я новый проект пробовал создать и скопировал туда только данный функционал, проблема осталась. но, закинув этот же код в другой проект, где я так же использовал ресайклер, подменив только тот ресайклер на "не рабочий", то там все нормально.

Answer (score 1):

На английском стеке предложили решение, которое мне помогло, необходимо добавить одну строчку после setLayoutManager.

```
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    mRecyclerView.getRecycledViewPool().setMaxRecycledViews(0, 0);
```